# How to get Missed call & SMS count

Tags: android, events, sms, counter

I want to get the count of missed calls and unread messages in my application. and I'd like to open the relevant application when user click on the count.

Now biggest problem is how to get the count?

I searched online but couldn't find any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html

Take a look at this `CallLog` class. All you need is to query the phone for any calls then extract missed one (оr do this when you are querying the phone, in the selection arguments). The same applies for the messages. SMS are stored in the Content provider under `"content://sms/"`

Then just get the count of rows in the Cursor that is return by the query. :)

I hope this helps.

For missed calls:

```
String[] projection = {
    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL,
    CallLog.Calls.TYPE
};
String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" + CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE;          
Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(
    CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
    selection,
    where,
    null,
    null
);
c.moveToFirst();    
Log.d("CALL", ""+c.getCount()); //do some other operation
if (c.getCount() == SOME_VALUE_TO_START_APP_ONE) //...etc etc
```

In the where clause you set condition for selection of data. In our case we need everything which type equals `CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE`. We select project the Name of the caller and his number, ofcourse you can specify more information to be queried like type of number like mobile, home, work.
The expression is equivalent to SQL query, something like: `SELECT CACHED_NAME, CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, TYPE FROM CONTENT_URI WHERE TYPE=MISSED_TYPE`

This requires permissions to be added to the Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

For querying SMS `ContentProvider`:

```
Uri sms_content = Uri.parse("content://sms");
Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(sms_content, null,null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
Log.d("SMS COUNT", "" + c.getCount()); //do some other operation
// Here proceed with the what you wanted
if (c.getCount() == SOME_VALUE_TO_START_APP_ONE)//...etc etc
```

You can go deeper in the content tree like specifying the type of sms, like: `content://sms/sent` or `content://sms/inbox` and add projection and selection for the second argument of the `query()` method like, name, person, status of the message (like the Calls example).

This requires permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you point me to some tutorial. I can hardly understand the documentation as I'm a real NooB :(

Comment: @MayuMayooresan I provided you with example I wrote for you. I hope my short explanation was clear enough. Good luck.

Comment: thank for your code i have used, String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" + CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE + " AND " + CallLog.Calls.NEW + "=1" to get new missed call (unviewed missed call). :)

Comment: ERROR -> getContentResolver() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have enough reputation to answer @Prasad question comment about

**ERROR -> getContentResolver() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}**

`getContentResolver()` is part of application context, so if you are using a BroadcastReceiver use context in `onReceive()` function like this

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.getContentResolver()
}
```

If you are using the code above inside an Activity, then you can use

```
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
```

also make sure to use [Ctrl + Shift + O (O not zero)] to organize imports

[Key Shortcut for Eclipse Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583339/key-shortcut-for-eclipse-imports)