# Key Shortcut for Eclipse Imports

Tags: java, eclipse

It's been a while since I last used Eclipse.  I used to love this handy key shortcut that added all the imports to the top of the source file, but I've forgotten it.  Does anyone know what this shortcut is?

Comment: If you can remember just one shortcut, remember Control Shift L, which will will give you a handy dandy popup list of the other shortcuts.

Comment: Try finding it yourself for a start: Googling "eclipse shortcut import" yields [this](http://www.allapplabs.com/eclipse/eclipse_shortcuts.htm) as the first hit.

Comment: Like this: http://bit.ly/18BLtQb @EmilLundberg

Comment: Returning two years later I notice my previous comment is very rude. My apologies.

Comment: @EmilLundberg I've found this post exactly on this way :-)

Answer (score 191, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (<-- an 'O' not a zero)

**Note: This shortcut also removes unused imports.**

Comment: what about `static import`?

Comment: WHats the key to import neccessary imports in eclupse?

Answer (score 45):

Some useful shortcuts. You're looking for the 1st one...

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> : Organize imports
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> : Open Type
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>    + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> : Close all Opened Editors
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> : Open declarations
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> : Open Editor
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> : Line Comment
7. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> :    Rename
8. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> : extract to Local Variable
9. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> :    extract to Method
10. <kbd>F3</kbd> : Open Declaration

Source [Here](http://sureshkrishna.wordpress.com/2007/09/15/top-10-eclipse-shotcuts/)

Answer (score 21):

Some other useful shortcuts:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> : **R**ename
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> : Word wrap
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> : Move the selected elements
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> : **I**nline refactoring
5. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> : Extract **M**ethod refactoring.
6. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> : Extract **L**ocal Variable
7. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> : Block selection mode
8. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd>:  selects enclosing elements
9. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>: Focus on eclipse element to know plugin implementation details.
10. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>: Plugin implementation details.
11. <kbd>F4</kbd> : Type Hierarchy
12. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> : *Open* **T**ype
13. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>: *Open* Type in **H**ierarchy
14. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>: Call **H**ierarchy
15. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>: Reference in workspace
16. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>: Quick Search for selected text
17. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>: **O**rganize imports
18. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>: Add import for currently selected.
19. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>: Shows you a **L**ist of your currently defined shortcut keys
20. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>: Occurrence in current file
21. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>: *Open* plug-in **A**rtifact
22. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>: Two side by side editors with current file
23. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> : Parameter Hints
24. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Mouse hover : To view javadoc
25. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Mouse hover : To view source code
26. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> : Content Assist
27. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>O</kbd> : Outline
28. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>: **T**ype Hierarchy
29. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> : Open Search Dialog
30. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> : Quick Fix
31. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NUM_KEYPAD_DIVIDE</kbd> : Collapse All code blocks
32. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NUM_KEYPAD_MULTIPLY</kbd> : To open all code blocks
33. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>left arrow</kbd>  : Open recently closed file

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ any key :Direct actions (on text mostly)

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ any key : Indirect actions

---

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> It is originally used with other chars by shell for perform special function. (In Mac <kbd>Command</kbd>)

<kbd>Alt</kbd> It enables alternate uses for other keys.

---

The above shortcuts are default, if we want to change shortcuts we can do. In eclipse -> Windows -> preferences -> keys. Where we can find all shortcuts with full details:
[image]

and
https://shortcutworld.com/IntelliJ-IDEA/win/IntelliJ_Shortcuts
https://shortcutworld.com/Eclipse/win/Eclipse-Helios_Shortcuts
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/migrating-from-eclipse-to-intellij-idea.html#Shortcuts

Comment: https://www.jrebel.com/blog/intellij-idea-tutorial

Comment: Upvote for the only answer that mentions Mac.

Answer (score 6):

You also can enable this import as automatic operation. In the properties dialog of your Java projects, enable `organize imports` via `Java Editor` - `Save Action`. After saving your Java files, IDE will do organizing imports, formatting code and so on for you.

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ just inserts them automagically; no shortcut required.  If the class name is ambiguous, it'll show me the list of possibilities to choose from.  It reads my mind....

Comment: Eclipse can do it as well, but it's not default option.

Comment: That's why I love IntelliJ - sensible defaults help to keep it out of my way when I don't want to worry about it but right there when I need it.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> : Show Imports

This displays imports as you're typing a non-standard class name provided the proper references have been added to the project.

This works on partial or complete class names as you are typing them or after the fact (Just place the cursor back on the class name with squigglies).

Answer (score 1):

**CTRL + 1** can also be used which will suggest to import.

Answer (score 0):

For static import select the field and press Ctrl+Shift+M

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can't remember all the shortcuts. You will forget many of them for sure. 
In this way, you can recall it and get the work done quickly.

Press 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

And type whatever the hell you want :) It's a shortcut for shortcuts

[image]