# How to count the number of missed calls in Android

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I know that how to get missed call alerts, but I do not know how many number of missed calls I have. So how can I count this number of missed calls?

I am using this code in `oncreate`:

```
TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       TelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(),PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

After that I am using this code to get an alert on a missed call:

```
class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
switch (state) {
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
if (ring == true && callReceived == false) {
missedcallno=incomingNumber;
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It was A MISSED CALL:" + incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
default:
break;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7621988/5275436

For Missed calls:

```
String[] projection = { CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, CallLog.Calls.TYPE };
           String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE+"="+CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE;          
           Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection,where, null, null);
           c.moveToFirst();    
           Log.d("CALL", ""+c.getCount()); //do some other operation
```

and declare permission in manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"></uses-permission>
```

***Detail about selection and selectionArgs***

**selection**
A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will return all rows for the given URI.

**selectionArgs (where)**
You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs, in the order that they appear in the selection. The values will be bound as Strings.

Comment: it showing error on this  The method "getContentResolver()" is undefined for the type Missedcall.TeleListener   and  ''selection" cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: actually i have to send one message only after when i got 5 missed call from a particular Number ,for this i have to count no of missed call so please help me to get no of missed call